# GStreamer dies when trying to put to KVS stream from RTMP source

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to take an rtmp source and have KVS ingest it.  I am running the following command on a Raspberry:

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 playbin rtmpsrc location="rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live live=1"   ! decodebin3 ! videoconvert   ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1280,height=960,fra
merate=30/1   ! x264enc  bframes=0 key-int-max=45 bitrate=500   ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc,alignment=au   ! kvssink stream-name="kvs-stream-3" storage-
size=512       access-key="xxx"       secret-key="xxx"       aws-region="eu-west-1"
```

I am using this build without issue to take from rtsp source.  But, ramp fails as follows:

[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:33:749.968 GMT] logStreamInfo():  Codec id: V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:33:750.004 GMT] logStreamInfo():  Track type: TRACK_INFO_TYPE_VIDEO
[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:33:750.040 GMT] logStreamInfo():  Track cpd: NULL
[INFO ] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:188.096 GMT] writeHeaderCallback(): RequestId: fc6cd48f-998e-4682-b75c-ce9918668e8f
[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:188.399 GMT] describeStreamCurlHandler(): DescribeStream API response: {"StreamInfo":{"CreationTime":1.674743285888E9,"DataRetentionInHours":720,"DeviceName":"Kinesis_Video_Device","IngestionConfiguration":null,"KmsKeyId":"arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:995138708603:alias/aws/kinesisvideo","MediaType":"video/h264","Status":"ACTIVE","StreamARN":"arn:aws:kinesisvideo:eu-west-1:995138708603:stream/halo-crowd-kvs-stream-3/1674743285888","StreamName":"halo-crowd-kvs-stream-3","Version":"lWuCgSJfP3kGjDl92JIU"}}
[INFO ] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:190.401 GMT] describeStreamResultEvent(): Describe stream result event.
[WARN ] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:190.743 GMT] describeStreamResult(): Retention period returned from the DescribeStream call doesn't match the one specified in the StreamInfo
[INFO ] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:661.314 GMT] writeHeaderCallback(): RequestId: 91892bc6-d2d6-43ca-bdda-746f54ab7d25
[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:661.549 GMT] getStreamingEndpointCurlHandler(): GetStreamingEndpoint API response: {"DataEndpoint":"https://s-5ac677c0.kinesisvideo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"}
[INFO ] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:664.648 GMT] getStreamingEndpointResultEvent(): Get streaming endpoint result event.
[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:664.854 GMT] getStreamingTokenHandler invoked
[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:664.993 GMT] Refreshing credentials. Force refreshing: 1 Now time is: 1688073994664941338 Expiration: 18446744073709551615
[INFO ] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:665.125 GMT] getStreamingTokenResultEvent(): Get streaming token result event.
[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:665.312 GMT] streamReadyHandler invoked
Stream is ready
Failed to set pipeline to PAUSED.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
[INFO ] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:667.361 GMT] Freeing Kinesis Video Stream kvs-stream-3
[INFO ] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:667.550 GMT] freeKinesisVideoStream(): Freeing Kinesis Video stream.
[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:34:667.658 GMT] curlApiCallbacksShutdownActiveRequests(): pActiveRequests hashtable is empty
[INFO ] [29-06-2023 21:26:35:068.551 GMT] freeKinesisVideoClient(): Freeing Kinesis Video Client
[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:35:068.704 GMT] curlApiCallbacksShutdownActiveRequests(): pActiveRequests hashtable is empty
[DEBUG] [29-06-2023 21:26:35:471.601 GMT] freeKinesisVideoClientInternal(): Total allocated memory 0
[WARN ] [29-06-2023 21:26:35:471.764 GMT] curlApiCallbacksShutdown(): curlApiCallbacksShutdown called when already in progress of shutting down

Any idea's anyone?